# Can I chat (not VOIP) in commander mode when playing on a tablet?

Tags: battlefield-4

I can see the text box in the upper left hand corner, but I haven't found a way to type there.  I want to be able to talk to my entire team instead of clicking on each squad and repeating myself via VOIP.

Can I talk in the chat feed via my tablet?  If so, how?

*I am running on an iPad with a bluetooth keyboard*

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately it is not possible to text chat (ie: type, not use VoIP) in the Commander app on both Android and iOS. Currently this is limited to VoIP communications with your team.